# Set UID/GID bits on NFS file system

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a system where to the *main server* (homes, nfs, ntp, queue...) can log-in only root – all the other users use *front-end host* with NFS-mounted home directories (RW) and all other software directories (read-only).

My problem is, that time to time, if root or normal user with sudo makes some administrative works on *front-end* some homes of normal users getting set-uid/gid bits (drwsr-sr-x). If it happens usually the user can't log-in (as long as permission for his home are not changed to drwxr-xr-x).

The last time I saw it after compiling some new software (*normal user* `configure;make`) and installation from the same directory as root (`su` and `make install` or direct as *normal user* `sudo make install`).

Can somebody explain me why it happens and what should I do to get rid of this problem?

*p.s.* I'm using CentOS 5.7

Comment: SetUID/GID bits are NOT Sticky bits!